# redirect Access rules with Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am doing an app that requires authentication. In the index page of the app, I specified access rules like this

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('deny',
            'actions'=>array('index','register','login','password'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
        array('allow',
                'users'=>array('*')
            ), 
        );
    }
```

At the first rule, the actions 'index','register','login' and 'password' are made unaccessible to authenticated users. However, I do not want to show this message

```
Unauthorized
You are not authorized to perform this action.

You do not have the proper credential to access this page.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

...to the authenticated users when they try to access those actions. Instead, I want to redirect them to another page. It would be useful if i could do something like this at the first rule

```
array('redirect',
    'actions'=>array('index','register','login','password'),
    'users'=>array('@'),
    'url'=>array('home/index'),
    ),
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### They 'll make you an offer you can't refuse

Starting with Yii v1.1.11 `CAccessRule` defines the [`deniedCallback`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule#deniedCallback-detail) property that easily allows you to define a redirect when access is denied. I don't want to steal [Iain Gray's thunder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12255226/50079), so go upvote his answer (thanks to the [commenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804751/redirect-access-rules-with-yii/9805509?noredirect=1#comment23814136_9805509) who alerted me to this as well).

The original answer follows.

### Option 1: extend Yii to enable this functionality (correct)

To do this we will need to write our own classes to be used instead of [`CAccessRule`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule) and [`CAccessControlFilter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter). For `CAccessRule` we just need to add one additional property:

```
class MyAccessRule extends CAccessRule {
    public $redirect; // just add this property
}
```

For `CAccessControlFilter` we want to make it recognize the value of this property and act upon it. To do this, we need to override the [`preFilter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter#preFilter-detail) method. Starting from the [stock implementation](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/auth/CAccessControlFilter.php#100), make a few changes:

```
class MyAccessControlFilter extends CAccessControlFilter {
    protected function preFilter($filterChain)
    {
        $app=Yii::app();
        $request=$app->getRequest();
        $user=$app->getUser();
        $verb=$request->getRequestType();
        $ip=$request->getUserHostAddress();

        foreach($this->getRules() as $rule)
        {
             if(($allow=$rule->isUserAllowed($user,
                                             $filterChain->controller,
                                             $filterChain->action,
                                             $ip,
                                             $verb))>0) // allowed
                 break;
             else if($allow<0) // denied
             {
                 // CODE CHANGED HERE
                 $request->redirect($app->createUrl($rule->redirect));
                 return false;
             }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then we also need to override the [`setRules`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter#setRules-detail) method, to instruct the filter to use the `MyAccessRule` class instead of the standard `CAccessRule`. Again, we modify the [stock implementation](http://code.google.com/p/yii/source/browse/tags/1.1.10/framework/web/auth/CAccessControlFilter.php#80) by changing the line

```
$r=new CAccessRule;
```

to read

```
$r=new MyAccessRule;
```

After creating these classes, we have to also inject them into Yii's pipeline. To do this, override [`filterAccessControl`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#filterAccessControl-detail) on the base controller class; again, taking the [stock implementation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#filterAccessControl-detail) as reference and making a small change:

```
public function filterAccessControl($filterChain)
{
        $filter=new MyAccessControlFilter;  // CHANGED THIS
        $filter->setRules($this->accessRules());
        $filter->filter($filterChain);
}
```

That's it! You can now take advantage of the extra functionality in any controller by supplying the new `redirect` parameter to the access control filters like this:

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array('deny',
              'actions'=>array('index','register','login','password'),
              'users'=>array('@'),
              'redirect'=>array('home/index'),
        ),
    );
}
```

### Option 2: implement access control inside each action (to be avoided)

If you are not comfortable with subclassing Yii's core components, another option **that I do not recommend** is to embed both access control and redirection logic inside each controller action that you want to protect, or overriding the [`beforeAction`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#beforeAction-detail) method on your controllers to cover multiple actions from one location.

Comment: Great answer!  I'm looking for something similar and will see where I get with Option 1.

Comment: @WallyLawless: Glad to help; I also made a small edit to add an example of how this new functionality can be used.

Comment: Quick note:  If you don't put a redirect rule in place then it will always place you at 'webroot' on failure.  You can fix that by checking: `if($rule->redirect) { /* do redirect */ } else { /* do default accessDenied */ }`

Comment: Note: In my overridden implementation of CAccessControlFilterprivate I did not have access to the private property $_rules;  To fix this, I added private $_rules to MyAccessControlFilter and added 

public function getRules()
{
 return $this->_rules;
}

Comment: Make sure you read Iain Gray's answer below everyone! It works since v1.1.11 and saved me time and headache.

Comment: @SyntaxError: Hey, thanks for the heads up. I edited the answer to point to Iain Gray's solution as the best option going forward.

Answer (score 29):

Since  Yii v1.1.11 you can do the same thing with a callback and a closure, and just the default classes:

```
array('deny',
'actions'=>array('index','register','login','password'),
'users'=>array('@'),
'deniedCallback' => function() { Yii::app()->controller->redirect(array ('/home/index')); }
),
```

Comment: After having problems with the accepted answer (due to my own error I'm sure) this one worked perfect for me.

Comment: How does it works? I mean, can I use it in 'allow' rule ? Can you show description of it?

Answer (score 4):

this one worked for me since yii 1.1.11:

```
    array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
            'deniedCallback' => $this->redirect('/')
        ),
```

or use a static method in a Class:

```
'deniedCallback' => array('ClassName', 'staticMethodName'),
```

Comment: if you dont write callback in from of a callback, it will be executed everytime.
here is it written in form of a statement.

Comment: this is just a demo and executed everytime, because the condition on top  means "deny every user"

Answer (score 1):

`$request->redirect($app->createUrl($rule->redirect));`

Should be:

```
if(is_array($rule->redirect) && isset ($rule->redirect[0])){
    $request->redirect($app->createUrl($rule->redirect[0]));
}
```