# Specifying Access Rules Specific Error Message In Controller

Tags: yii

I am currently using yii 1.1.10 version in which I am trying to specify rules specific error message by defining message in accessRules function as specified below:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('xxx','yyy'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'message'=>'You must be logged in as Member to perform this action.',
            'actions'=>array('zzz','aaa',),
            'expression'=>'AuthenticationHelper::isSessionUserAdmin()',
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
            'message' => "This is a generic message.",
        ),
    );
}
```

However in case expression fails, I am able to view only message that has been specified against deny rule which is "This is a generic message.", even when second evaluation fails. Any points to achieve desired behaviour is highly appreciated.

Comment: A [`message`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessRule#message-detail) will only be used for `deny` rules. It doesn't make sense to show a message if something is allowed.

Comment: Hi Michael, I am agree to your viewpoint but think from my perspective, one want to show different messages in case of failure of different rules. Otherwise displaying just a single generic message irrespective of which rule have failed doesn't make much sense to end user.

Thus in this case the only thing which I can think to provide custom message is by removing expression from rules and then manually checking same in my actions, and in case of failure displaying error message appropriately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804751/redirect-access-rules-with-yii.

Answer (score 0):

You can propably do it this way:

```
array('allow',
    'message'=>'You must be logged in as Member to perform this action.',
    'actions'=>array('zzz','aaa',),
    'expression'=>'AuthenticationHelper::isSessionUserAdmin()',
),
array('deny',
    'message'=>'You must be logged in as Member to perform this action.',
    'actions'=>array('zzz','aaa',),
    'expression'=>'!AuthenticationHelper::isSessionUserAdmin()',
),
```