# how to create users in yii rights module?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I have installed the rights module in yii. Also I have created the user roles and the operations. But it does not work. I want to know where will I create users for the roles?

Answer (score 0):

As per your style just paste this "user/admin/create".

```
look like http://url/index.php?r=user/admin/create
```

Now on view page you can fetch all the roles of your db using

```
$all_roles=new RAuthItemDataProvider('roles', array( 
'type'=>2,
));
  $data=$all_roles->fetchData();
```

Then create a drop down using it. And u can create user based on your role

```
<div>
    <label for="type_id">Type</label>
    <?php echo CHtml::dropDownList("Type",'',CHtml::listData($data,'name','name'));?    > 
</div>
```

And assign it in your controller

```
$authorizer = Yii::app()->getModule("rights")->authorizer;
```

$authorizer->authManager->assign($type, $model->id);

Answer (score 0):

You create roles for users not vice versa ( or at least this is my approch, if you want to merge with it ).

For roles you can look at this question : [redirect Access rules with Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804751/redirect-access-rules-with-yii)

The best approach is to use CAccessControlFilter class, defined in Yii framework, and to extend this by your roles/giving access class.

You preFilter method will look like this :

```
protected function preFilter($filterChain)
    {
        $app=Yii::app();
        $request=$app->getRequest();
        $user=$app->getUser();
        $verb=$request->getRequestType();
        $ip=$request->getUserHostAddress();

        foreach($this->getRules() as $rule)
        {
            if(($allow=$rule->isUserAllowed($user,$filterChain->controller,$filterChain->action,$ip,$verb))>0) // allowed
                break;
            elseif($allow<0) // denied
            {
                if(isset($rule->deniedCallback))
                    call_user_func($rule->deniedCallback, $rule);
                else
                    $this->accessDenied($user,$this->resolveErrorMessage($rule));
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

And your WebUser class will look like this:

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser {

  // Store model to not repeat query.
  private $_model;


  // access it by Yii::app()->user->name
  function getName(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return $user['Name'];
  }


  // access it by Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()
  function isAdmin(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user['Type']) == 4;
  }

  function isEditor(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user['Type']) == 3;
  }

  function isOrganizer(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user['Type']) == 2;
  }

  function isNormal(){
    $user = $this->loadUser(Yii::app()->user->id);
    return intval($user['Type']) == 1;
  }

  // Load user model.
  protected function loadUser($id=null)
    {
        if($this->_model===null)
        {
            if($id!==null)
                $this->_model=User::model()->findByPk($id);
        }
        return $this->_model;
    }
}
```

I used that with success in one of my university projects https://github.com/RazvanADumitru/EventsPlanning